# How to call a function to update a value after popping a screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-layout

Screen 1: shows list of item with add button.
Screen 2: form to add a new item to the list.

Screen 2 >> Screen 1 - While calling navigator.pop() in screen 2, how to call method/setState (to update list) in screen 1?
Can anyone help me out?

I don't want to relaunch screen again. I just need to run a method to update my list after popping previous screen?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

When you navigate from Screen 1 to Screen 2, you use the `push` method. The `push` method returns a `Future` object.
You can use the `then` method of `Future` to execute your code after Screen 2 was popped from the navigation stack.

```dart
Navigator.of(context)
  .push(MaterialPageRoute(
     builder: (context) => Screen2(),
  ))
  .then((value) {
    // you can do what you need here
    // setState etc.
  });
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use **Provider** or **BLoc** or you can await for the result when you push the page

Comment: that's other option to get this done. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this :

```
// this method waits for the pop to be called
var data = await Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen()),
);

debugPrint(data); 

// here the second argument is the data 
Navigator.pop(context, "data");  // popped from LoginScreen().
```

output

data

Same method can also be done like below

```
   // this method waits for the pop to be called
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen()),
).then((data){
    // then will return value when the loginScreen's pop is called.
    debugPrint(data); 
});
```

Here is a good article to look into this 
https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-push-pop-push-1bb718b13c31

Answer (score 0):

`Navigator.pop` has a second argument called result.
You could then return the value that you need to the first page that will read it as the return value of `Navigator.push`