# Flutter: How to automatically trigger a function when a route was pushed on to the stack?

Tags: flutter

I want to trigger automatically trigger a function when a screen is pushed on to the stack. I have been doing some research and I think this could be achieved by extending `WidgetsBindingObserver` class.

Once I have extended it, calling `didPushRoute` method should be the way to go. So the first thing is to ask if I could be right with this approach.

The second question, and request if you will, would be to ask for a specific implementation or example of this, if it’s the case that the mentioned approach is correct. Doing the same when popping a route is another thing I want, but I think it is on the same line. The main idea of this approach would be to make specific things happen **automatically** when navigating.

**I am looking for something that always happen when the current route / or a specific stateless or stateful gets covered by another screen, rather than manually executing a function with navigator, otherwise I would need to do this for every new push I want to do.**

Thanks in advance for the feedback and let me know if have to explain something deeper of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: `I want to trigger a function when I push a new route` there is something just for that , it's called a route observer you can take a look here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html

Comment: Thanks @Ainz-sama. I know this exists, but I wonder if there is another option for that, since I don't want a route-observer for my whole app but rather something for a specific stateless or stateful widget on the screen.

Comment: so if you dont want "route-observer for my whole app" - what do you want to achieve then?

Comment: I mean something like a listener

Comment: what listener? when new route pops from the stack?

Comment: Yes, when popping or pushing. Maybe the only way to go is the route-observer. But what about WidgetsBindingObserver. Is that then not a correct way? I would've thought one could do this just with one widget, rather than with the whole app. I mean I'm just wondering. It sure can be that my suggested approach is not the one.

Comment: well i dont understand what is your goal really? you want to push a new route, then do something in that new route and then return from it (by pressing back button or calling `Navigator.pop`) and finally the original route to be notified when new route pops?

Comment: Say I have a widget in my first route, which has a value I always want to change when another route covers the route where my widget is. This ideally should happen throughout the whole app, since I could be using the same widget in many places. But I wonder if this method could be simply inside the widget.

Comment: even with that i have no idea what you want to achieve, sorry... i hope someone else will help you then

Comment: For example I create a TextField whose focus I want to lose every time I navigate to another screen. There are times where the focus is till there when I return (and it is not just about autofocus: false). The question was oriented towards asking if there was something like a method to override to tell the widget to unfocus every time it is not visible.

Comment: Okay @pskink thank you anyways :)

Comment: Ainz-sama and pskink you were right. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying lots of methods to achieve what I wanted, I realized that the comments above telling the way to go would be with a route observer are right. So here I am posting the code that helped me achieve what I wanted. This code makes reference to: [Flutter - How the NavigatorObserver class works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46165705/flutter-how-the-navigatorobserver-class-works)

```
// Register the RouteObserver as a navigation observer.
final RouteObserver<PageRoute> routeObserver = RouteObserver<PageRoute>();
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Container(),
    navigatorObservers: [routeObserver],
  ));
}

class RouteAwareWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  State<RouteAwareWidget> createState() => RouteAwareWidgetState();
}

// Implement RouteAware in a widget's state and subscribe it to the RouteObserver.
class RouteAwareWidgetState extends State<RouteAwareWidget> with RouteAware {

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context)!);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didPush() {
    // Route was pushed onto navigator and is now topmost route.
  }

  @override
  void didPopNext() {
    // Covering route was popped off the navigator.
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container();

}
```

For me concretely was this method that helped to achieve the desired behavior:

```
  @override
  void didPushNext() {
    // TODO: implement didPushNext
    super.didPushNext();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you navigate from Screen 1 to Screen 2, you use the push method. The push method returns a Future object. You can use the then method of Future to execute your code after Screen 2 was popped from the navigation stack.

```
Navigator.of(context)
  .push(MaterialPageRoute(
   builder: (context) => Screen2(),
  ))
  .then((value) {
    // you can do what you need here
    // setState etc.
  });
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61644205/13252751

Comment: I am looking for something that always happen when the current route gets covered by another, rather than manually executing a function with navigator, otherwise I would need to do this for every new push I want to do.

Comment: if this may help:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EcAwFpC9S8s&list=PLjxrf2q8roU3ahJVrSgAnPjzkpGmL9Czl&index=38

Answer (score 1):

For me the Ivan Yoed solution worked, but give me an error in `didChangeDependencies` function:

> The argument type `ModalRoute<Object?>` can't be assigned to the parameter type `PageRoute<dynamic>`.

To solve this just change this:

```
routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context)!);
```

To this:

```
routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context) as PageRoute);
```

Thanks Ivan!

Answer (score -2):

You can look at the [official documents](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data) for passing data or invoke function with navigator callbacks. As a workaround you can also insert some function before push and call it before pop.

Comment: I think think this answer could be improved, otherwise it seems like the case of 'your answer is in another castle' https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/949217